# How to pull selected revisions with Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

We have a repository with several Eclipse projects with Java classes and now need to simultaneously support development both Java 7 and Java 6 versions.   The Java7 stream will be the new main development stream but we need to manage both and deploy both to production environments.

I understand branching a little but that only seems to pull all the changes from one repository to another.  I need to leave some changes behind.

The Java 7 local repository looks like this

```
  [old hist] -> [a] -> (head on default)    
                   \->[j7] -> [d] -> [e] -> [f] (working dir)
```

Where [j7] only contains changes related to using Java 7 (e.g. new .classpath files)

We need a Java 6 stream and it needs to include changes [d], [e], [f] but not [jv7]

```
[a] ->          /-> [d] -> [e] -> [f] -> [b] (head on default)
    \->[j7] -> [d] -> [e] -> [f]
```

The default path now has the latest work from the Java7 stream except [j7] and it still has the old Java 6 configuration files.

This seems like a common problem that most branching and merging discussion don't mention. 
Any tips will be appreciated.

Comment: Look into the graft command (if your version is recent enough) or the transplant extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other possible solutions that might leave the history a bit clearer:

### option A:

Merge the head of Java7 branch into the head of the Java6 branch & then backout the [j7] changeset on the Java6 branch.

### option B:

1. Merge changeset [j7] into the head Java6 branch & discard all the changes from the java7 branch (if using TortoiseHg then this is an option labelled "Discard all changes from merge target (other) revision.")
2. Merge the head of the Java7 branch into the head of the Java6 branch.

We use option B quite a lot if we're making config changes in a branch repo.
(think of it as merging in the history of the changeset without merging the change).

When doing a merge like this, we always include "merge of xxx - discarding changes" in the commit message (so that it is obvious when browsing history)

### How to "merge discarding changes" from the command line:

Mercurial's CLI doesn't have a dedicated "merge discarding changes" option, but their "tips and tricks" [help page](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Keep_.22My.22_or_.22Their.22_files_when_doing_a_merge) explains how to achieve this from the command line:

```
hg -y merge --tool=internal:fail RevOfHeadToDiscard
hg revert --all --rev .
hg resolve -a -m
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that. Here's one. You can pull all changesets from the Java7 repos to the Java6 repos, then run merge. *Before* comitting your merge in Java6, manually modify the configuration files to undo the changes from [j7], then commit the merge.

You will only have to do this once for this changeset, meaning that if later you pull other changes from Java7 to Java6, you will not have to bother about [j7] again.

Comment: Good answer and timely too.  I appreciate that it only depends on basic mercurial commands without extensions.